# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: database

I have following code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

        cnn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Books values('"+ textBox1.Text +"','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','"+ dateTimePicker1.Text +"','" + textBox6.Text + "','" +textBox7.Text+ "')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cnn.Close();
        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox2.Text = "";
        textBox3.Text = "";
        textBox4.Text = "";

        textBox6.Text = "";
        textBox7.Text = "";

        MessageBox.Show("book add to Books succesfull");

    }
}
```

when i run project it shows below error :

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.